# EOF error in nested loops

Tags: python-3.x, while-loop, nested-loops

This program is a bit of a pain. It has to find the average tempearatures. If it is below 60, it must count how many numbers (that were averaged out) were below 60. It must do the same for any number above 80 if the average temperature is above 80. EDIT: instead of asking the user for the # of values, the program will keep accepting until given a blank value. This is my program:

```
def main():

    sums = 0.0
    count = 0
    heating = 0
    cooling = 0
    temp = (input("enter a number, <enter> to quit: "))
    while temp != " ":
        x = float(temp)
        sums = sums + x
        count = count + 1
        temp = eval(input("enter a number, <enter> to quit: "))
        avg = sums/count
        if avg < 60:
            if temp < 60:
                heating = heating + 1
        if avg > 80:
            if temp > 80:
                cooling = cooling + 1

    print(avg, heating, cooling)

main()
```

This is the error I keep getting. I have tried variations of asking for the input with and without the eval, and also with switching the temp between float and int. I keep getting errors, more commonly, this one.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/heatingcooling.py", line 24, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Python33/heatingcooling.py", line 13, in main
    temp = eval(input("enter a number, <enter> to quit: "))
  File "<string>", line 0

   ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Any ideas on how to get this program to run would be much appreciated. As a side note, we are not allowed to use raw inputs, which seemed to be the most common solution for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current loop confuses `temp` with `x` a few places. You need to be consistent about them because they're different types (`temp` is a string and `x` is a `float`). Here's a fixed version of the code, with a few other fixes, like testing for an empty string and providing an initial value for `avg`:

```
sums = 0.0
count = 0
heating = 0
cooling = 0
avg = 0      # need an initial value for this, in case the first input is empty!
temp = input("enter a number, <enter> to quit: ") # temp is always a string
while temp:      # equivalent to testing temp != ""
    x = float(temp)
    sums = sums + x
    count = count + 1
    avg = sums/count
    if avg < 60:
        if x < 60:          # compare to x here, not temp
            heating = heating + 1
    if avg > 80:
        if x > 80:          # here too
            cooling = cooling + 1

    temp = input("enter a number, <enter> to quit: ") # moved this to the end of the loop

print(avg, heating, cooling)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're in Python 3.x, removing the `eval()` should work with the `input(...)`

```
temp = input("enter a number, <enter> to quit: ")
```

The Python 3 documentation for `input` can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input)

**Edit** It sounds like you need to convert your temp variable into an int after you get it from the input() method, which is a str by default.

```
temp = float(input("enter a number, <enter> to quit: "))
```

Also, when you get your first `temp` variable, remove the outside parentheses:

```
temp = (input("enter a number, <enter> to quit: "))
```

to

```
temp = input("enter a number, <enter> to quit: ")
```

Assuming your enter a numeric value, you should then be able to cast this value to a float once inside the while loop.

**Edit2**

In your while loop change it to this:

```
while temp:  # or while temp != ""
    # etc.
```

This will resolve the `ValueError: could not convert string to float` error. You were terminating the while loop upon entering a space " ", but when the user hits enter, the input is really an empty string "". Thus, you were still entering the while loop and then trying to cast the empty string "" input into a float, which then raised the ValueError.

Comment: That just gives another error message saying it cannot add strings and floats in the line where sum = sum + temp. It also will not let me convert the temp into an int or a float

Comment: it simply says that the string cannot be converted to a float. Your idea of putting <int(input ...> worked. But now I am getting this error:   
    File "C:/Python33/heatingcooling.py", line 16, in main
    temp = int(input("enter a number, <enter> to quit: "))
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

Comment: Use float, not int, and this error should be resolved.

Comment: @JohnZ that does not work. Now I am getting this error : ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: @JohnZ Same as earlier ValueError: could not convert string to float.